# In Bash, how to capture exit status code from a command nested within a complex statement

Tags: bash, exec, eval, file-descriptor, exit-code

I'm relatively new to working with bash. I've inherited this bit of code to run a command via SLURM on an HPC system:

```
CMD="srun -srunParam1 ... -srunParamN ./scriptToRun.sh -scriptParam1"
exec 5>&1
results=$(eval "${CMD}" | tee - >&5))
```

That all works just fine.

But, **I need to capture the exit status of just `eval "${CMD}"`**, and don't know how to do it.

Initially, I put `exitStatus=$?` after the `results=...` command; but, I believe that's catching the status of assigning a value to the `results` variable, and not of `eval ${CMD}`

The script goes on to process the output that is in $results. I don't really understand why the file descriptor has been opened here (or, how to properly use file descriptors). But, I'll save that for further research/a separate question.

> EDIT: I commented out the bits with the file descriptor, and observed that the script still works, but $results does not contain the output from running $CMD - it only contains the post-processing of $CMD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash has `PIPESTATUS`:

```
results=$(eval "${CMD}" | tee - >&5; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}) 
exitStatus=$?
```

Note that in the code above we are examining the exit status of a command that was run inside a subshell (`$(...)`); it would not work to access `PIPESTATUS` in the parent.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this one. A good illustration would be `true | true | false | true | false | false; declare -p PIPESTATUS`

Comment: Just what the doctor ordered. I googled a bit to research PIPESTATUS, and came upon: `https://www.shellscript.sh/tips/pipestatus/`. @Fravadona, your comment is right in line with the way that site describes PIPESTATUS

Answer (score 0):

One way to get status is to save it in a file :

```
results=$( { eval "${CMD}"; echo $? > /tmp/cmd_status.txt; } | tee - >&5)) 
# Process /tmp/cmd_status.txt here
```